# List the hardware info and status in my computer

Tags: hardware

1. I was wondering how to list all the
   hardware info in my computer?

   Both terminal and GUI solutions
   please.
2. Is there a single utility to monitor
   most hardware's working status? Just like some software in Windows?

Thanks and regards!