# How to list the simplest way of hardware specification?

Tags: hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List the hardware info and status in my computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47623/list-the-hardware-info-and-status-in-my-computer)

I want to know the computer's hardware specifications.

Like:

```
 cpu:xxx
 motherboard:xxx
 memory:xxx
 video card:xxx
 pci:xxx
```

Thank you~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo lshw` should be what you need

Comment: Why I can't find the video card's type?

Comment: you should find it under `*-display` (possibly under `*-pci:0` if your card is pci)

Comment: obs: if you want an html output (better to look at), use `sudo lshw -html > hwlist.html` and open the file created with a browser. If you want only the display adapter name: `sudo lshw -short | grep display`