# Ubuntu 11.10 recently installed, purple screen, then text shown

Tags: installation, 11.10, 64-bit, hp-pavilion

I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 in my Hp Pavillion a1520n. However, with any version of Ubuntu that I tried to install, a purple screen shows up, and after a black page with white text thats starting all these services, but after it doesnt  boot the system.

I'm new to this and I have no clue what to do to fix it. Can you help me?

Comment: Does your computer show the boot menu at start-up? (black screen where you can choose between different Operating Systems) If yes, select the option recovery mode and try to proceed with the  'failsafe X' option. If this works and you can log in to your system please open a terminal and type 'lspci' (without quotes) and post the output here. As this is likely a graphic card issue  the command will show the card or internal gpu your pc is using, so we can then install the drivers

Comment: Please add more info... use a liveCD and scratch a little more: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47623/list-the-hardware-info-and-status-in-my-computer and http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into add that info to your question. =D

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for a workaround. 
-ALT+F1 or F2 etc to get to another session
-Enter in credentials
-Enter "startx" no quotes in the prompt and hit enter
It should load up your desktop and get you GUI access to the system. I just set autologin for my user so I dont know how to fix the actual login screen not starting.