# Internal Speakers not functioning after removing headphone

Tags: 11.10, sound, headphones, vaio, speakers

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I have a Sony VAIO VPCEA23EN Laptop. The problem is when i detach the headphone from jack, the internal speakers don't function.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the volume? when using the headphone jack do you turn down the sound down to a lower level? - it will stay at that volume until you manually increase it again.

Comment: Could you add more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47623/list-the-hardware-info-and-status-in-my-computer and add it to the question.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Mark Rooney increasing the volume worked for me.